# What exactly mean the ${...} in the perl?

Tags: arrays, perl

Thinking about the next. Have a LIST

```
qw(a b c);
```

now, assign the LIST into nameless (anonymous) ARRAY

```
[ qw(a b c) ]
```

so the next

```
use 5.016;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
my $x = [ qw(a b c) ];
say ref $x;  #ARRAY - the $x is an ARRAY reference, and
say $x->[1]; #prints "b", and
say [ qw(a b c) ]->[1]; #works too
```

but what happens now?

```
use 5.016;
use warnings 'all';
use diagnostics;
say ${[ qw(a b c) ]}[1];
```

it prints `b`, but

```
my $y = ${[ qw(a b c) ]};
```

is an error,

```
Not a SCALAR reference at pepe line 6 (#1)
    (F) Perl was trying to evaluate a reference to a scalar value, but found
    a reference to something else instead.  You can use the ref() function
    to find out what kind of ref it really was.  See perlref.

Uncaught exception from user code:
    Not a SCALAR reference at pepe line 17.
```

So, whats mean the contruction ${.... }

- It "works" in the `say` (prints the second element of the anonymous array), but don't understand why
- but can't assign it into variable

And the hint from the `diagnostics` is not very helpful, because how I should use the `ref` when I can't assign? What I missed from the `perlref`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`${ EXPR1 }[ EXPR2 ]` is an array index dereference. It returns the element at the index returned by `EXPR2` of the array referenced by the reference returned by `EXPR1`.

`${ $array_ref }[ ... ]` is to array references as `$array[...]` is to arrays.

---

`${ EXPR }` that's not followed by `[` or `{` is a scalar dereference. It returns the scalar referenced by the reference returned by `EXPR`.

`${ $scalar_ref }` is to scalar references as `$scalar` is to scalars.

---

As you can see, when dealing with a reference, you can use the same syntax as you normally would, except that you replace the name of the variables with `{$ref}` (keeping the leading sigil).

As such, `@{ $array_ref }` is to array references as `@array` is to arrays.

```
say @{[ qw(a b c) ]};
```

---

This is the essence of the chart in my earlier post [Mini-Tutorial: Dereferencing Syntax](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=977408). See also:

- [References quick reference](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=69927)
- [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)
- [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)
- [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)
- [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html)

---

Oops, I thought you had

```
say ${[ qw(a b c) ]};   # Want to print a b c
```

You have

```
my $y = ${[ qw(a b c) ]};
```

You want

```
my $y = [ qw(a b c) ];
```

`[]` creates an array and a reference to that array, and returns the latter, kinda like

```
my $y = do { my @anon = qw(a b c); \@a };
```

Comment: @ysth, ah yes, though you mean `$ BLOCK [ EXPR ]`. I'll adjust (using something a little less confusing).

Comment: @ysth, On second thought, I'll leave it as is. While the syntax is more permissive than I indicated, I didn't claim it's limited to that syntax, and I don't see a clear way of incorporating that information. Any misdirection here is acceptable.

Comment: You can safely remove everything after the "Oops". ;) As you can see, in my 1st example i'm already used your suggestion `$x = [ qw(a b c) ];` . The minitutorial is GREAT, but still have problems. **When the `$ar` is an array-ref, WHAT IS the `${$ar}`?**

Comment: @cajwine in that case, the `${$ar}` is resulting in a 'not a scalar ref' error, because the `${$ref}` is the scalar dereferencing, just like ikegami said above. You will almost never see a scalar reference. Maybe as a one-value-object, but there are not many scenarios where you need this. Think of it like this: if you have `@array` and you want the first index, you say `$array[0]`. With the array ref `$arr` you either say `$arr->[0]`, or the verbose `${ $arr }[0]`. Maybe it's easier if it's longer: `${ $foo->{bar}->{i_hold_an_array} }[0]`

Comment: @cajwine added answer to the question from your comment

Comment: @cajwine, Actually, I did cover that. `${$ar}` is a scalar dereference. That's why it's failing when `$ar` holds an array reference.

Comment: Yes, now understand - finally - thank you :). Seems you're write faster as I can read and understand ;)

Answer (score 4):

Given an array `@arr` and an arrayref `$aref = \@arr`, then inside the following groups of expressions all lines are equivalent:

Accessing the whole array:

```
@ arr
@{$aref}
```

Accessing a single scalar in the array:

```
$ arr   [$i]
${$aref}[$i]
$ aref->[$i]
```

Accessing a slice of entries:

```
@ arr   [$i .. $j]
@{$aref}[$i .. $j]
```

(the spaces are included for alignment and are not recommended for actual code).

The `${}`, `@{}`, … are circumfix dereference operators. However, accessing a single scalar changes the sigil from `%` or `@` to `$`. Without references, this makes total sense. With them, it's just slightly complicated, until you read [`perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) (esp. the two reference usage rules).

Answer (score 1):

With the

```
${$ar}[0]
```

you said to perl: *take `$ar` as `arrayref` and return me 1st element from the array to what the reference `$ar` points.*

With the construction

```
${$sr}
```

you saying to perl: *take the `$sr` as `SCALAR REF` and return the value of the scalar to what the reference `$sr` points.*

Therefore, the answer to your question from the comment: *When the $ar is an array-ref, WHAT IS the ${$ar}?* is:

**When the $ar is an $array-ref, the ${$ar} is an** ***ERROR***,

because you said to perl - take the scalar-ref, but the $ar is NOT scalar-ref (it is arrayref).

The next example show your constructions clearly:

```
use 5.012;
use warnings;

my @arr = qw(a b c);
my $aref = \@arr;

my $myval = "VALUE";
my $sref = \$myval;

say $aref->[0];
say ${$aref}[0];
say ${$sref}; #your construction - here CORRECTLY points to an scalar

#say ${$aref} #ERROR because the ${$xxx} mean: take scalar ref, but the $aref is array ref.
```

Comment: oh shit. :( now understand. the perl looking for an scalar reference and found array reference - therefore it is an error. I'm a bit slow, but get it ... ;)